# Unable to update CV

Tags: support, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I am trying to edit my CV and update the work experience. But it looks like I can't add experience (job, project etc.) in my profile. The old edit tab is no more, I have tried both story view and classic view.

I want to add my new job experience and add some projects. How can I do that now?

Comment: Hm, I just added a new item to my story, as well as a project, and did not come across any issues. Can you provide some examples (maybe a step-by-step walkthrough) on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @rla4 After your comment I tried again, this time it works :-/ I am not sure was it temporary issue. I haven't added anything yet, but form appear. Previously it didn't :(